# Redirect does nothing in react-router-dom

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

```
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch, Redirect } from "react-router-dom";
class App extends Component {
  constructor(){
    super();
    this.state = {
      windowWidth: window.innerWidth,
      navOpen: true,
      user: {
        id: '',
        name: '',
        email: ''
      }
    };
  }

  signIn = (data) => {
    if(data){
      this.setState({user: {
        id: data.id,
        name: data.name,
        email: data.email
      }});
      return <Redirect to='/'/> /*Right here when it come to here the page does nothing and no errors?*/
    }
  }

render() { 
    return(
      <div className='app'>
      <Router>
        <NavBar onNavClick={this.onNavClick} navOpen={this.state.navOpen}/>
        <Switch>
          <Route path="/" exact component={() => <Home />} />
          <Route path="/about" exact component={() => <About />} />
          <Route path="/contact" exact component={() => <Contact />} />
          <Route path='/catalogue' exact component={() => <Catalogue />} />
          <Route path='/login' exact component={() => <Login signIn={this.signIn} onRouteChange={this.onRouteChange}/>}/>
        </Switch>
      </Router>
      </div>
      );
  }
}
export default App;
```

I have tried again and again but it will not change the page to the root and will not come with any errors with it. I have looked everywhere but its just the same thing. The log in page just runs sign in function. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You can't redirect like that from a function. You will need to use `props.history.push('/')` or something similar

Comment: Please share your `Login` component

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Issues

1. You can't just return JSX from a function callback like that and expect it to be rendered, you will need to use the `history` object and issue an imperative redirect, i.e. `history.replace("/");`.
2. The redirect won't work from the `signIn` callback since the `App` component is *outside* the routing context provided by `Router` being rendered by `App`.
3. You are using the `Route`'s `component` prop to render components but you are using an inline function, this will actually unmount and remount the components anytime `App` rerenders.

## Solution

1. Move the `Router` component higher in the React tree in order for `App` to be able to access the same routing context the `Route`s are. You will need to also pass the `history` object to `App`. This would be trivial if `App` were a functional component where you could use the [useHistory](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Hooks/usehistory) React hook, but since it isn't you will need to use the *slightly* less trivial [withRouter](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/withRouter) Higher Order Component and inject the [route props](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Route/route-props).

   Access `history` from injected props:

   ```
   signIn = (data) => {
     if (data) {
       this.setState({user: {
         id: data.id,
         name: data.name,
         email: data.email
       }});
       this.props.history.replace("/");
     }
   }
   ```

   Decorate `App` with `withRouter` HOC:

   ```
   export default withRouter(App);
   ```

   Wrap `App` in the `Router`.

   ```
   <Router>
     <App />
   </Router>
   ```
2. Fix the routes by using the `component` prop correctly, and using the `render` prop when you need to pass additional props.

   ```
   <Switch>
     <Route path="/about" component={About} />
     <Route path="/contact" component={Contact} />
     <Route path='/catalogue' component={Catalogue} />
     <Route
       path='/login'
       render={() => <Login signIn={this.signIn} onRouteChange={this.onRouteChange}/>}
     />
     <Route path="/" component={Home} />
   </Switch>
   ```

Comment: Thank you very much! I would never of got this.

Answer (score 0):

for the `/` for the home you need to specify

`<Route exact path="/" component={Home} />`

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look at the history https://reactrouter.com/web/api/history. For example, you can write history.push("/location"); the page will be redirected, and the states still don`t get lost. For me, it has been the easiest way to handle the redirecting in react.